# filter extracted link from webpage using htmlagility - vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

## Problem one:

I have a program for extracting urls of a webpage (`WebSource`) with a specific content (`/articles/`)

```
Dim links As New List(Of String)()
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(WebSource)
For Each link As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    Dim att As HtmlAttribute = link.Attributes("href")
    If att.Value.Contains("/articles/") Then
        links.Add(att.Value)
    End If
Next
```

Is it possible to search in urls and filter them by two value, for example in a tech site i want find all urls contain `/articles/` and `LG`

## Problem two:

Extracted urls are not complete HTTP address for example one of my results is

```
/articles/car
```

Instead of complete address for example

```
http://website.com/articles/car
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking **ONE** content now . for checking multiple items in htmlagility you can use multiple `if` statement as follow

```
If att.Value.Contains("content1") Then
    If att.Value.Contains("content2") Then
        If att.Value.Contains("content3") Then
            links.Add(att.Value)
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: :| string ??? no . if i use `"/articles/" & "LG"` actually i use `"/articles/LG"`. do you know anything about strings ?????????

Comment: This is so stupid! Why had not my mind ... thank you very much